# PLSQL - execute queries that were built in SELECT

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm executing the following query:

```
SELECT
'ALTER TABLE '||TABLE_NAME||' MODIFY ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' VARCHAR2('||DATA_LENGTH||' CHAR);'
FROM
    USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE
    DATA_TYPE LIKE '%CHAR%'
AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%VIEW'
ORDER BY
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME;
```

The output is in itself queries to alter the tables I select from 'USER_TAB_COLUMNS'.
Such as:

```
ALTER TABLE ADM_FILTER_ELEMENT_REF_T MODIFY ELMNT_REF_CONTEXT VARCHAR2(1020 CHAR);
```

I would like to know how can I catch this output and execute the queries?
The query is designed to be executed in a `.sql` script which is called from batch file.

Please advise.

Comment: `execute immediate` comes to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could loop on the result of the query in an anonymous block and use `execute immediate` to execute them.

Something like this:

```
begin
    for q in (SELECT
                'ALTER TABLE '||TABLE_NAME||' MODIFY (' || COLUMN_NAME || ' VARCHAR2('||DATA_LENGTH||'));' query
                FROM
                    USER_TAB_COLUMNS
                WHERE
                    DATA_TYPE LIKE '%CHAR%'
                AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%VIEW'
                ORDER BY
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    COLUMN_NAME
                ) LOOP
        execute immediate q.query;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: I am not sure if the statement is correct but yes, immediate queries are solution I wanted to suggest a minute ago.
[EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm)

Comment: I tried your solution, but I'm getting 'ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option' error.

Comment: @DavidFaiz - I provided solution to show how to use the result. Your query syntax had problem - after modify, the column and it's datatype needs to be inside parentheses. Updated the answer.

Comment: There seems to be a stray semicolon inside the quoted string.